# R mapdist vs gmapsdistance

Tags: r, api, google-maps, distance

I am pulling drive times and distances using the distance matrix API in R. Currently I am utilizing the mapdist function which returns the time and distance for an origin and destination.

However, I also found the gmapsdistance function in R. This function also allows for further parameters such as eliminating ferry/toll routes ect (which may become important in the future).

I was curious to whether one is better than the other. So I utilized the same origin and destination to see whether the results are the same using the code below:

```
mapdist(from = "02081", to = "89801", mode = "driving")

gmapsdistance(origin = "02081", destination = "89801", mode = "driving",
                  key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

And the following outputs were returned:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 9
  from  to          m    km miles seconds minutes hours mode   
  <chr> <chr>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>   <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1 02081 89801 4185463 4185. 2601.  141708   2362.  39.4 driving
> gmapsdistance(origin = "02081", destination = "89801", mode = "driving",
+               key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
$Time
[1] 141630

$Distance
[1] 4185370

$Status
[1] "OK"
```

I though the distances and times would return the same value, but they are slightly off? Has anybody encountered this and have any idea why they may return different values?

Also - Is it possible to eliminate the possibility of toll routes/ferry routes using the mapdist function?

Comment: Please speciffy the packages used.  It could be that they used different algorithms to optimize.  The `km` seems to be the same

Comment: I am using the gmapsdistance and ggmap package

Comment: what about the `mapdist` function

Comment: It returned the 1x9 tibble. The distance seems to be very close but not exactly the same. I just wanted to know is it better to use one vs the other